# Why does the XML language not show on a GitHub repository's language bar

Tags: android, xml, github, programming-languages

On a GitHub repository (take [Google's I/O app](https://github.com/google/iosched) for example), there is a coloured bar showing the programming languages used (underneath details about commits, branches, releases and contributors).

However, I was wondering why it doesn't show languages such as XML (in the case of the Google I/O app, it has numerous XML layout and resources, but they are not counted/shown at all on the bar).

Similarly, files with extensions such as `.gradle`, `.bat`, `.yml`, `.gitignore`, etc. are not counted either.

Is there a reason for this?

Comment: https://github.com/github/linguist

Comment: https://api.github.com/repos/google/iosched/languages

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I [opened an issue](https://github.com/github/linguist/issues/2818) on [GitHub's 'linguist' repository](https://github.com/github/linguist), and found why XML, Gradle, etc are not shown on the language bar. Here is a summary of the comments and replies from that, which answer this question:

> Only languages classified as `markup` or `programming` are displayed in the language bar.

because...

> this is generally what people are looking for when browsing a repository

In other words...

> people are usually more interested in the implementation language than the build script

Comment: I wish this would change. Especially as an Android developer, at the very least, XML should be counted.